# How to get fal object instead of array when using flux:field.inline.fal

Tags: typo3, flux

In my flux content template configuration section I define an image field like this:

```
<flux:field.inline.fal label="Image" name="images" maxItems="1" minItems="0" showThumbs="1"/>
```

In my flux content template main section I debug the output:

```
<f:for each="{v:resource.record.fal(table: 'tt_content',field: 'images', uid: '{record.uid}')}" as="image" iteration="iterator">
  <f:debug>{image}</f:debug>
</f:for>
```

The debuging output shows an array but what I need is the FAL object of that image I added in the backend.

I googled a lot and found some older posts from 2015. All say it is not possible to get the fal object(!) in flux. Is it still true? Do you know any way?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom ViewHelper:

```
<?php

namespace Cmichael\Typo3projectprovider\ViewHelpers\Content;

/* FalViewHelper
* To get fal object by image uid (respectivly in flux templates)
* Usage example: <cm:content.fal referenceUid="{image.uid}">
* */

class FalViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

  /**
   * @var bool
   */
   protected $escapeOutput = false;

  /**
   * Initialize arguments.
   *
   */
   public function initializeArguments() {
      $this->registerArgument('referenceUid', 'integer', 'File reference uid', true, 0);
   }

  /**
   * Return file reference
   *
   * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference|null
   */
   public function render() {
      $referenceUid = $this->arguments['referenceUid'];
      $fileReferenceData = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_page->checkRecord('sys_file_reference', $referenceUid);
      return $fileReferenceData ? \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getFileReferenceObject($referenceUid) : $referenceUid;
   }
}
```